# Can I show a matrix equation has a unique minima by showing it is convex?

Tags: calculus, matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider the following equation
$$
\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{A}\circ\mathbf{A})= \hat{\mathbf{P}}
$$

where $\mathbf{P}$, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{P}}$ are all square matrices with positive elements.  I want to solve for $\mathbf{A}$.  Due to the Schur product in there I don't think I can do so analytically (though if I can that would be great and would resolve all of my problems).  The Schur product is there because the matrix $\mathbf{A}\circ\mathbf{A} = \tilde{\mathbf{A}}$ needs to have all positive elements.  Given these constraints, I've decided to try and find $\mathbf{A}$ by gradient descent, thereby minimising the Frobenius norm of the difference between the LHS and RHS of the equation.
$$
\frac{d}{d\mathbf{A}}\|\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{A}\circ\mathbf{A}) - \hat{\mathbf{P}}\|_{F} = 0
$$

I would like to know if its possible to show that this optimisation has a unique minima.  It seems to me that would be possible by showing the function is convex everywhere, but then in the context of the matrix equation I'm not convinced I know how to do that.  I would have thought that showing the function is convex in each individual element of $\mathbf{A}$ would do the trick?

Otherwise, I believe the typical argument for a function being convex if its 2nd derivative is +ve, but in this case would I have to show that the 2nd derivative is positive in all its elements?  Or something like the 2nd derivative is positive definite?

Comment: When you say that the matrix equation has a minima, what do you exactly mean? Is it that the Frobenius norm is minimal?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I will clarify the question!

Answer (score 1):

Define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= A\odot A \\
Y &= \hat P \\
M &= I\otimes P \\
}$$
where $I,P,X,Y\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}\;$ and $\;(\odot,\otimes)$ denote the Hadamard and Kronecker products respectively.

Now [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the equation
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\vc(Y) &= (I\otimes P)\,\vc(X) \\
y &= M\,x \\
}$$
This can be formulated as a [Non-Negative Least-Squares (NNLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) problem
$$\eqalign{
&\min_x &\|Mx-y\|^2_2 \\
&{\rm s.t.}\;\;&x_k\ge 0 \\
}$$
which can be solved by a variety of methods, e.g. interior point method or projected subgradients.

One extremely simple method is the *sequential coordinate-wise* algorithm.

After initialization
$$\eqalign{
x&= 0, \quad w &= -M^Ty \\
}$$
an inner iteration runs through all components $(k=\o:n^2)$ of the $x$ vector
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\beta}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
q &= M^TM\e_k \\
\a &= \min\!\left(x_k,\; \frac{w_k}{q_k}\right) \\
x &= x - \a\e_k \\
w &= w - \a q \\
}$$
where $\e_k$ is the $k^{th}$ basis vector. This iteration is repeated until convergence is obtained.

Afterwards the $A$ matrix can be recovered using an elementwise square root
$$\eqalign{
A &= \operatorname{reshape}\big({\sqrt x},\, n,n\big) \\
\\
}$$

### Update

The algorithm can also be applied to the matrix form of the problem
$$\eqalign{
&\min_X &\|PX-Y\|^2_F \\
&{\rm s.t.}\;\;&X_{ij}\ge 0 \\
}$$
Initialize
$$\eqalign{
X = 0,\quad W = -P^TY \\
}$$
and iterate over all components $\,(i=\o:n,\;\;j=\o:n)\,$ of the $X$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
Q &= P^TP\,\e_i\e_j^T \\
\a &= \min\!\left(X_{ij},\; \frac{W_{ij}}{Q_{ij}}\right) \\
X &= X - \a\,\e_i\e_j^T \\
W &= W - \a Q \\
}$$
until convergence. Then extract the elementwise square root
$$A=\sqrt X$$

Comment: Thank you!  Is this a writing of NNLS to the matrix form?  Or a different iteration?

Comment: @Pablo Plemmons mentioned the coordinate-wise algorithm in a [2009 survey article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.157.9203) which is where I first read about it. I don't recall if it was the vector or matrix form. There are many other NNLS algorithms presented in that article, so it is worth reading.

Comment: In the case where the elements of $W$ are all negative, then this algorithm converges after a single step, as far as I can tell, because then $beta = W_{ij}/Q_{ij}$ and so $W = 0$ going into the second iteration.  Or have I misunderstood the implementation?

Comment: @Pablo You are half correct. It is true that $\beta=W_{ij}/Q_{ij}$ for the first iteration, but that does not make $W=0$.  So you must continue with the iterations until $X$ does not change between iterations.  Even after $X$ converges, $\,W\ne 0\;$

Comment: In fact, you will discover that, on a component-wise basis $\,X_{ij}=0 \;\implies\; W_{ij}\ne 0\,$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $F(A)=P(A\odot A)-\hat{P}$.
Using http://www.matrixcalculus.org, we can see that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}\|F(A)\|_2 = 2\frac{P^TF(A)\odot A}{\|F(A)\|_2}$$

This is what you need to solve. If you can ensure that no element of $A$ is zero then it simplifies to $P^TF(A)=0$ or $F(A)=0$ if $P$ is inversible, which is not really helpful. However, it provides you with the gradient and a gradient descent might be doable.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but I don't think I see how to o from here to showing the original function is convex in $A$.  Can you clarify?  If I use this to calculate the second derivative, I'm still unclear if I'm looking for a matrix with all positive elements, or just a postive-definite matrix.

Comment: It will depend on your matrices but if there is only one point for which we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}\|F\|_2=0$ and if $A\to\infty$ makes $\|F\|_F$ diverge then you can only have one minimum.